# Allow multiple billing and shipping addresses only for backend

Tags: frontend, backend, shipping-address, customer-address, billing-address

We currently use only 1 country for the billing and shipping addresses.
I want to add some other countries to apply, when adding an order trough the backend.

But that should only be possible in the backend, not on the frontend.

How can I achieve that?

Comment: This is manageable from admin section.
Please verify the admin configuration settings.

Comment: Thanks! Where can I find that option? Because I really do not know that one? I only know the way to add it for front and backend.

Comment: Please go to
System >> configuration >> Sales >> Shipping Settings >> Options >> Allow Shipping to Multiple Addresses